# strcmp problems

Tags: c

i need to compare what the user inputs to what i have previously stored using strncpy...i know that the strncpy part works, i run into problems when i compare input to puser->Username etc...

```
int admin_signIn(struct profile *puser)
{
 int i=0;


 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
  strncpy((puser+i)->UserName, "admin", strlen("admin")+1 );
  strncpy((puser+i)->Pwd, "password", strlen("password")+1 );

  printf("Enter admin user name:");
  fgets(input,10,stdin);
  rewind(stdin);   
  printf("Enter admin password:");
  fgets(input,10,stdin);

    //printf("the password is %s", puser->Pwd);    
   if(strcmp((puser+i)->UserName, input)==0 && strcmp((puser+i)->Pwd, input)==0)
    {
     printf("The Administrator username and password is incorrect, please try again\n");                                      

    }
   else
    {
     printf("the info is good\n");
    }

  }
   printf("max number of attepmpts exceded, goodbye!");   
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 when the inputs *do* match. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp Though you are overwriting the entered username with the entered password...

Comment: `strncpy()` is probably not the function you want to use in the first place. It wasn't designed to work with strings; it was designed to work with character arrays not necessarily zero-terminated. Make very sure your strings are terminated.

Comment: What is the `(puser+i)->UserName` supposed to accomplish? Why would use a different user profile for each iteration of attempting to get the username/password? It't not clear this is the source of the bug you're seeing, but doesn't seem to make sense in any case. I don't believe you can apply `rewind` to standard input meaningfully either (it's equivalent to calling `fseek`, which isn't meaningful on standard input either).

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but the way you're using `strncpy()` is exactly equivalent to using a plain old `strcpy()`. So using `strcpy()` insterad won't fix anything, other than making the code a bit more clear. But as pmg pointed out, it shows a misunderstanding of why and when `strncpy()` should be used (which is almost never).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this too:

instead of:

```
  strncpy((puser+i)->UserName, "admin", strlen("admin")+1 );
  strncpy((puser+i)->Pwd, "password", strlen("password")+1 );
```

you can do:

```
strcpy((puser + i)->UserName, "admin");
strcpy((puser + i)->Pwd, "password");
```

and

```
  char password[10];
  char username[10];

  fgets(username,10,stdin);
  rewind(stdin);   
  printf("Enter admin password:");
  fgets(password,10,stdin);
```

and then:

```
   if(strcmp((puser+i)->UserName, username)==0 && strcmp((puser+i)->Pwd, password)==0)
   {
      /* correct username and password. Do something.. */
   }
```

Now you're comparing the username and password typed by user.

Comment: thank you....i was changing my program to be somewhat like that, but yours is cleaner, but i am still having problems...i think my problem now is my loop

Comment: well it is not my loop that is the problem, if i get rid of the fo loop altogether it still does not compare

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other problems mentioned, it looks like you're using one variable (`input`) to hold the username and password simultaneously; that seems unlikely to be successful...

```
 printf("Enter admin user name:");
 fgets(input,10,stdin);
 rewind(stdin);   
 printf("Enter admin password:");
 fgets(input,10,stdin);
if(strcmp((puser+i)->UserName, input)==0 && strcmp((puser+i)->Pwd, input)==0)
```

Comment: i had input as a global variable but i have now changed it to input 1 and input 2 so basically i have if(strcmp(puser->UserName, input1)==0 etc...  but it still is not working...ok i see what you mean about strncpy @michaelburr...i changed it back to strcpy.....@jerrycoffin  what i am supposed to do is store admin and password for the generic admnistrators password, and i also have to store 5 made up usernames and passwords and then have my program act like someone is trying to login if that makes sense